# Ruby memory leak

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I am using Ruby with Sequel, PostgreSQL (the 'pg' gem), and em-webosket for parsing some data and storing it in a database. I'm running my script via the 'daemons' gem.

Sometimes I get this error in daemons log when my script crash. How can I find the source of the bug?

- `I, [2015-07-07T11:15:32.476751 #21491]  INFO -- : *** below you find all exception objects found in memory, some of them may have been thrown in your application, others may just be in memory because they are standard exceptions ***`
- `E, [2015-07-07T11:15:32.477956 #21491] ERROR -- : stream closed (IOError)`
- `E, [2015-07-07T11:15:32.478231 #21491] ERROR -- : failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)`
- `E, [2015-07-07T11:15:32.478350 #21491] ERROR -- : stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`
- `E, [2015-07-07T11:15:32.478758 #21491] ERROR -- : exception reentered (fatal)`
- `E, [2015-07-07T11:15:32.481995 #21491] ERROR -- : No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - /home/cloud/paralela/ws.rb_monitor.pid (Errno::ENOENT)`

  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/pidfile.rb:103:in `delete' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/pidfile.rb:103:in `zap' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/monitor.rb:114:in `stop' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:158:in `stop_all' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/controller.rb:64:in `run' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons.rb:144:in `block in run' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:88:in `call' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:88:in `catch_exceptions' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons.rb:143:in `run' ``
  - `` server.rb:3:in `<main>' ``
- `E, [2015-07-07T11:15:32.483217 #21491] ERROR -- : cannot load such file -- sequel (LoadError)`

  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/paralela/ws.rb:6:in `<top (required)>' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application.rb:218:in `load' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application.rb:218:in `start_load' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application.rb:297:in `start' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:151:in `block (2 levels) in start_all' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:150:in `fork' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:150:in `block in start_all' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:149:in `each' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:149:in `start_all' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/controller.rb:66:in `run' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons.rb:144:in `block in run' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:88:in `call' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:88:in `catch_exceptions' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons.rb:143:in `run' server.rb:3:in `<main>' ``
- `E, [2015-07-07T11:15:32.487555 #21491] ERROR -- : cannot load such file -- sequel_pg (LoadError)`

  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sequel-4.23.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:855:in `<top (required)>' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sequel-4.23.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:97:in `load_adapter' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sequel-4.23.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:26:in `adapter_class' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sequel-4.23.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:55:in `connect' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sequel-4.23.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:95:in `connect' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/paralela/ws.rb:12:in `<top (required)>' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application.rb:218:in `load' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application.rb:218:in `start_load' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application.rb:297:in `start' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:151:in `block (2 levels) in start_all' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:150:in `fork' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:150:in `block in start_all' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:149:in `each' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:149:in `start_all' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/controller.rb:66:in `run' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons.rb:144:in `block in run' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:88:in `call' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:88:in `catch_exceptions' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons.rb:143:in `run' ``
  - `` server.rb:3:in `<main>' ``
- `E, [2015-07-07T11:15:32.491328 #21491] ERROR -- : cannot load such file -- pg (LoadError)`

  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/paralela/ws.rb:8:in `<top (required)>' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application.rb:218:in `load' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application.rb:218:in `start_load' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application.rb:297:in `start' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:151:in `block (2 levels) in start_all' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:150:in `fork' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:150:in `block in start_all' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:149:in `each' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:149:in `start_all' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/controller.rb:66:in `run' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons.rb:144:in `block in run' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:88:in `call' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:88:in `catch_exceptions' ``
  - `` /home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/daemons-1.2.2/lib/daemons.rb:143:in `run' ``
  - `` server.rb:3:in `<main>' ``